# Android Keyboard (Input) method for german language

Tags: java, android, layout, input

Environment :

```
Android application
Android 2.2 or above 
eclipse 3.7
```

I want to set `german` keyboard or `input method` for the user who want s to enter details and should be  the pure german keys .
Is there any way to do it ? if any one known this issue please suggest !!

Comment: So the user who is **not** using a device set to German should be able to enter ä, ö, ü, ...? Because if the device is configured for German, then that comes "for free". No need to do anything special. Also note that this is "only" a separate keyboard layout and does not require a fully-fledged input method.

Comment: @JoachimSauer how to configure input method programmatically in my application and i was giving option like english or german so m asking for input method